# Adding label to OpenStreetMap

Tags: openstreetmap, labeling, layers, editing

I've eaten at this amazing Brazilian BBQ restaurant in Calgary and I noticed its not on OpenStreetMap (OSM).

How do I add a label to OSM?

I am currently in the process of learning how to use QGIS and have been introduced to ArcGIS, I just need a refresher and some pointers on where to access reliable databases and upload my own layers or embed them into OSM [not sure exactly how its done at this point].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create an account on openstreetmap.org.
2. Navigate to the right area on the map, zooming in as close as you can.
3. Click 'Edit'.
4. There's a helpful run-through. Watch it. When it's finished...
5. Click 'Point'.
6. Click the place on the map where the restaurant is. An icon will be added.
7. Type 'restaurant' and press Enter.
8. Fill in as many fields as you think are relevant.
9. When you've finished, click 'Save' in the top right hand corner.

Answer (score 4):

If you would like to contribute to OpenStreetMap you will need to [sign up for an account](https://www.openstreetmap.org/user/new) and then choose an OSM [editor](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Editors).

Start with the [Beginners' Guide](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Beginners%27_guide).
After that, it's important to read the existing documentation on [how to contribute data](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Contribute_map_data) to the project, especially the OSM [tags](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_Features) and [mapping techniques](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mapping_techniques).